# Cloudera Issue while adding slaves, cloudera-manager-agent must have Version=5.3.0 and Build=155, exiting closing logging file descriptor

Tags: cloudera, slave, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

While adding slaves to the quickstart VM provided by cloudera I am getting the following error. It looks like incompatible built error but I am not sure. If so, how can I resolve it. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
    /tmp/scm_prepare_node.FmQxihPe 
    using SSH_CLIENT to get the SCM hostname: 10.0.96.100 49973 22 
    opening logging file descriptor 
    Starting installation script...
    Acquiring installation lock...
    BEGIN flock 4 
    END (0) 
    Detecting root privileges...
    effective UID is 0 
    Detecting distribution...
    BEGIN grep Tikanga /etc/redhat-release 
    END (1) 
    BEGIN grep 'CentOS release 5' /etc/redhat-release 
    END (1) 
    BEGIN grep 'Scientific Linux release 5' /etc/redhat-release 
    END (1) 
    BEGIN grep Santiago /etc/redhat-release 
    END (1) 
    BEGIN grep 'CentOS Linux release 6' /etc/redhat-release 
    END (1) 
    BEGIN grep 'CentOS release 6' /etc/redhat-release 
    END (0) 
    /etc/redhat-release ==> CentOS 6 
    Detecting Cloudera Manager Server...
    CentOS release 6.6 (Final) 
    BEGIN host -t PTR 10.0.96.100 
    END (127) 
    /tmp/scm_prepare_node.FmQxihPe/scm_prepare_node.sh: line 105: host: command not found 
    BEGIN which python 
    END (0) 
    BEGIN python -c 'import socket; import sys; s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET); s.settimeout(5.0); s.connect((sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))); s.close();' 10.0.96.100 7182 
    /usr/bin/python 
    END (0) 
    BEGIN which wget 
    END (1) 
    which: no wget in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin) 
    BEGIN wget -qO- -T 1 -t 1 http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname && /bin/echo 
    END (127) 
    /tmp/scm_prepare_node.FmQxihPe/scm_prepare_node.sh: line 105: wget: command not found 
    Installing package repositories...
    validating format of repository file /tmp/scm_prepare_node.FmQxihPe/repos/rhel6/cloudera-manager.repo 
    installing repository file /tmp/scm_prepare_node.FmQxihPe/repos/rhel6/cloudera-manager.repo 
    repository file /tmp/scm_prepare_node.FmQxihPe/repos/rhel6/cloudera-manager.repo installed 
    Refreshing package metadata...
    BEGIN yum clean all 
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror 
    Cleaning repos: base cloudera-cdh5 cloudera-manager extras updates 
    Cleaning up Everything 
    END (0) 
    BEGIN rm -Rf /var/cache/yum/x86_64 
    END (0) 
    BEGIN yum makecache 
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror 
    Metadata Cache Created 
    END (0) 
    Installing cloudera-manager-agent package...
    BEGIN yum list installed cloudera-manager-agent 
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror 
    Error: No matching Packages to list 
    END (1) 
    BEGIN yum info cloudera-manager-agent 
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror 
    Determining fastest mirrors 
    * base: mirror.nexcess.net 
    * extras: mirror.thelinuxfix.com 
    * updates: mirror.us.leaseweb.net 
    Available Packages 
    Name : cloudera-manager-agent 
    Arch : x86_64 
    Version : 5.3.0 
    Release : 1.cm530.p0.166.el6 
    Size : 3.8 M 
    Repo : cloudera-manager 
    Summary : The Cloudera Manager Agent 
    URL : http://www.cloudera.com 
    License : Proprietary 
    Description : The Cloudera Manager Agent. 
    : 
    : The Agent is deployed to machines running services managed by 
    : Cloudera Manager. 

    END (0) 
    Version : 5.3.0 
    cloudera-manager-agent must have Version=5.3.0 and Build=155, exiting 
    closing logging file descriptor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after spending an entire day trying to solve this issue I was able to fix it. The issue is repo and parcels are not on the same page, one of them has older build than other which causes issue while updating. Manually updating the master node solved the issue for me. Follow this article to upgrade if you encounter similar issue:-
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-manager/v5-0-0/Cloudera-Manager-Administration-Guide/cm5ag_upgrade_cm5.html?scroll=cmig_topic_9_4